# Postpone materialized view creation

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

tl;dr: Is there any way to define a materialized view in postgres without filling it with data immediately, but on refresh only?

Background: I have a flyway repeatable script, that creates a materialized view with heavy aggregation on a huge chunk of data. Is there any possibility to create a view definition, so that it's mapped to hibernate entity without any error, but it can be empty and filled with data on refresh. It will be refreshed once a day at night, so I don't want to affect application startup time.

Stack: postgres 11, spring boot 2, hibernate 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `WITH NO DATA` option:

```
create materialized view bla_bla
as 
select *
from foo_foo
WITH NO DATA;
```

Quote from [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-creatematerializedview.html):

> `WITH [ NO ] DATA`
>   
>   This clause specifies whether or not the materialized view should be populated at creation time. If not, the materialized view will be flagged as unscannable and cannot be queried until REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW is used

This however means that any attempt to access that materialized view before it's refreshed will result in an error, rather than just an empty result.